# Android application with ActionBar stopped working(crashes) clicking the device home button

Tags: android, crash, android-actionbar, home-button

I have created a Android application with Action Bar tabs as like the below code.

```
 sActionBar = getActionBar();
```

with 3 tabs using Fragments. The application is crashed, while clicking the device home button. How to resolve this issue?

EDIT 1:

Here is the logcat information.

```
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:376)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-06 23:55:31.910: E/AndroidRuntime(4628):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post logcat output and possible code.

Comment: We need the logcat.  The bug is almost certainly in your onPause or onStop functions (the functions that get called when an app goes to the background).

Comment: I here updated the logcat information.